# Group Checkbox in ModalBottomSheet Flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

How to apply group checkbox in modalbottomsheet? I have create group checkbox and its work fine. But when I put it in to the modalbottomsheet the state not instantly changes (need to reopen to see value changes). I do have wrap the checkboxListTile with StatefulBuilder and give StateSetter. Any Solution? Thank you

here my codes

```
Column(
                          children: [
                            StatefulBuilder(builder:
                                (BuildContext context,
                                    StateSetter setState) {
                              return CheckboxListTile(
                                controlAffinity:
                                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                value: checkAllPermit,
                                title: Text('Permit', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    checkAllPermit = value;
                                    _permitType.forEach((tipePermit){
                                      tipePermit.value = value;
                                    });
                                  });
                                },
                              );
                            }),
                            ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: _permitType.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                                    (BuildContext context,
                                        StateSetter state) {
                                  return CheckboxListTile(
                                    controlAffinity:
                                        ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                    value: _permitType[index].value,
                                    title: Text(_permitType[index].title),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      state(() {
                                        _permitType[index].value = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: I am assuming your `_permitType` is the one that is not updating, right ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy yap, _permitType value should be updating when I click the checkbox for CheckAll checkbox for each _permitType as seen as the onChanged state.

Comment: single checkbox working fine

Answer (score 0):

`List.forEach` is useful in cases where you want to perform an operation using each element of the List.

But it is isn't a good approach when you want to update the List in your state.

When you do

```
_permitType.forEach((tipePermit){
  tipePermit.value = value;
});
```

You are just updating the references of the individual elements inside your `_permitType` and not actually updating the reference of your `_permitType`, which is causing your UI to not update.

Instead do this,

```
_permitType = _permitType.map((_) => value);
```

With this, you are using `map` to not just update each element to `value` but are also changing the reference of `_permitType` to this new List that you are getting by calling `.map`.

Secondly,

When you call the `StateSetter` that you obtain from the `StatefulBuilder`, only the widget inside the builder is re-built and widgets outside the `builder` will not rebuild.

In your use case, there doesn't seems to be any need for `StatefulBuilder` since you are not using the `context` that it is giving you.

So, just remove the `StatefulBuilder` and use it normally.

Comment: I think its still need the `StatefulBuilder` coz the `checkbox` is inside `modalBottomSheet`. I have try your suggestion and the value not even changing to true.  Thanks for the suggestion sir ;)